# Geodesic devation on a two sphere

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

So the [geodesic deviation equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation_equation) gives the relative acceleration between two geodesics in motion. But given a pair of geodesic (let's say on the two sphere) that start at the equator, separated by some distance. Is there a way to compute their separation as a function of time without using the geodesic equation? Let's say they're moving at northward toward the pole along a line of constant longitude at unit velocity.

Comment: I do not understand, what is time on the 2-sphere? That is a Riemannian manifold, not a Lorentzian one...

Comment: @V.Moretti $ds^2=-dt^2+dr^2+r^2d\Omega_2^2$ where $r$ is constant, thus $dr^2=0$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @V.Moretti Well, let's say they're moving at northward toward the pole along a line of constant longitude at unit velocity.

Comment: @Jim No, because if you keep r constant you do not find a geodesic of that spacetime.

Comment: @user44056 The geodesic deviation is usually understood for a congruence of (for instance timelike) geodesics in a given spacetime and the parameter along the geodesics is the proper time.  The sphere is not a Lorenzian manifold, so there is nothing like proper time. In a Riemannian manifold the natural  affine parameter along geodesics is the length parameter on the curves. In this case however there is nothing like an acceleration!

Comment: Also the notion of velocity is not defined: it has nothing to do with the mathematical objects taking place in the geodesic deviation equation in a Riemannian manifold. So it is not clear to me what your question actually mean.

Comment: @V.Moretti you absolutely can find a geodesic for a constant r. That would correspond to a geodesic over the surface, which is certainly possible

Comment: It is not a geodesic of the spacetime! Since it is Minkowski spacetime, geodesics are segments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re your edited question, this is just simple spherical geometry. If the initial separation is $d$ then the separation at time $t$ is $d \cos(vt/r)$, where $r$ is the radius of the sphere, $v$ is the vehicle speed and $t$ is time.

[image: Sphere]

The diagram shows a cross section through the poles. The vehicle is driving north at a velocity v, so the distance it drives in a time $t$ is just $s = vt$, so the angle $\theta$ is:

$$ \theta = \frac{vt}{2\pi r} 2\pi = \frac{vt}{r} $$

Suppose the vehicles start out at a separation $d$. The angular separation along the equator $\Delta\phi$ is:

$$ \Delta\phi = \frac{d}{2\pi r} 2\pi = \frac{d}{r} $$

As the two vehicles drive north the angular separation $\phi$ doesn't change, so we just need to calculate the circumference of the line of latitude at the angle $\theta$, $C_\theta$, and the separation will be $C_\theta\tfrac{\Delta\phi}{2\pi}$.

$$C_\theta = 2\pi r \cos\theta $$

So the separation $s$ is:

$$\begin{align}
 s &= 2\pi r \cos\theta \frac{\Delta\phi}{2\pi} \\
   &= 2\pi r \cos\left(\frac{vt}{r}\right) \frac{d/r}{2\pi} \\
   &= d \cos\left(\frac{vt}{r} \right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: A downvote? Did I get something wrong? (I answered in a hurry so it's entirely possible.)